# Escaping German umlauts in Pug

Tags: html, node.js, pug, html-entities

I've set up a small Node.js server running Pug as view engine.
When I write down some text Pug automatically escapes it except for umlauts (`ÄÖÜäööü`) and `ß`.
Is there a way to escape the characters in such a way that ä gets displayed as an actual ä? When using the entities or the html-entities I either get a black box with an exclamation mark or the actual escape sequence.

Comment: Can you give an example of your code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add

```
meta(charset="UTF-8")
```

to your page's head section.

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    meta(charset='UTF-8')
    title Title
  body
```

Comment: I did but it didn't.